# pstricks rput coordinates and rotation broken

Tags: pstricks, coordinates

when using pstricks rput, all coordinates are piled up and rotations are piled up and the rotation also doesn't work.
Anchorage and other functionality seems to work.

I'm using Xelatex on an Arch Linux system, with every package updated to the latest.

when running

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
  \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,5)
  \psgrid[gridcolor=gray,
    subgridcolor=lightgray](0,0)(5,5)
  \rput[bl](0,1){bottom left (0,1)}
  \rput[tr](5,1){top right (5,1)}
  \rput[Bl](0,2){Baseline left (0,2)}
  \rput{45}(1,4){rotate $45^{\circ}$}
  \rput{45}(3.5,3.5)
  {
    \psframe[linecolor=red](-1,-1)(1,1)
  }
  \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

i get

[image]

while it should generate

[image]

If you want to know some details, please include a command that i can use to get your answer (like package versions).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your errors.

Comment: I just encountered the same issue after reinstalling texlive